# MULTIPLE repeating table to submit to a SharePoint List

Tags: infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have an existing SP 2010 list New/Edit form which I have already customized in InfoPath for formatting, Now I need to modify the form to have multiple items insertion feature by using Repeating Table.

But on existing form I am facing following issues:

1) Not able to modify Data Connections

2) Data Connections " multiple list items with the form" option is not available

3) Repeating Table and Repeating section container control are not available.

Can anyone guide me how I can achieve multiple list items insertion on my existing List Form?

[image: section control]

[image: data connection wizard]

Answer (score 1):

What you describe cannot be easily done out of the box in a list form.

A list form can typically only manipulate the data for its own list,  not write several rows of data to another list.

If you want to use InfoPath, you'd need to start out with a browser form as the container, load the parent list data, load the child list items. To write back to the child list you'd need code of some flavour. List forms cannot use code, browser forms can.

If you don't want to roll your own, you could use something like [Qdabra's Qrules](http://www.qdabra.com/en/products/qRules.aspx) library, which can be configured to write to another list's data.

Comment: Thanks Teylun for reply, I don't have to save data to another list. Actually I have to modify the existing SP List Form which I have already modified in Infopath.    Now I am not able to add Repeating section or Repeating Table containers.